# Нужны ли знаки препинания между словом "адресу" и "ул. Островского"? Если да, то какие?

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно расставить знаки препинания?

> проживающих по адресу ул. Островского, 4

Answer (score 1):

Если адрес длинный и после адреса будет стоять точка, то можно поставить двоеточие:
"..., проживающих по адресу: ул. Островского, дом 4, строение 5, квартира 7".
А можно и не ставить — в принципе, к канцеляриту нет высоких литературных требований.

Answer (score 1):

Дело не в длине адреса. Двоеточие ставится, если адрес синтаксически не является частью предложения. Например:

> Я проживаю по адресу: ул. Островского, 4.

Но:

> По адресу ул. Островского, 4 я никогда не проживал.

Здесь "по адресу ул. Островского, 4" - обстоятельство места.